# Terminal "ls" command sorting flagged files

Tags: terminal, bash

```
ls -lO
```

lists "restricted" flagged files as well as the rest

Is it possible to limit the list just to these files and/or to list them sorted first or last in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grep for ‘restricted’ to restrict the results to just restricted files.

```
$ ls -lO | grep restricted
drwxr-xr-x@   5 root  wheel  restricted         160 21 Sep 05:05 System
drwxr-xr-x@  37 root  wheel  restricted,hidden 1184 21 Sep 05:17 bin
⋮
```

To sort by file flags, pipe to `sort -k 5`

```
$ ls -lO | sort -k 5      
total 20
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  wheel  -                   64  1 Sep 15:47 AppleInternal
⋮
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root  wheel  hidden               1 14 Dec 22:10 home
⋮
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  hidden,compressed  313 18 Aug 01:55 installer.failurerequests
⋮
drwxr-xr-x@   5 root  wheel  restricted         160 21 Sep 05:05 System
```